# Can the values from hashlib.sha1 library change between versions of Python?

Tags: python, hash, hashlib

I am using the hashlib.sha1 library to store file names in Python. e.g.:

```
 file_name = hashlib.sha1(url.encode()).hexdigest()
```

Is this library fixed, so that the same term entered would yield the same hash in different versions of Python?

Answer (score 1):

As long as there are no bugs that's how a hash function has to work.
If the hash would be different you couldn't log in anymore on many webpages since the only store a hash of your password.

That being said it could always be possible that there was a bug producing wrong results. On the other hand I guess those libraries are never really touched between releases, since there is nothing to do.

What are you trying to achieve though? Hashes are one way and I don't see any reason to hash a file name?